# Get scanned data from Panasonic FZ-N1 without focus on EditText?

Tags: android, events, android-intent, barcode-scanner

Have been trying to get the scanned data on scan button press in Panasonic FZ-N1 device, while not focused on any EditText fields. Tried using dispatchKeyEvent and Intent but was not able to.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Sharing code snippets of your attempts helps the community members to suggest solutions.

Comment: This article may be helpful. [TOUGHPAD(FZ-N1/FZ-X1)のバーコードリーダを制御する](https://sashimi4.hatenablog.com/entry/handle-toughpad-barcode-reader-from-android-java), [sasakii/ToughpadSimpleBarcodeReaderDemo](https://github.com/sasakii/ToughpadSimpleBarcodeReaderDemo)

Comment: @kunif Thank you for that, let me check using that and update